# Pass data to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple form component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="addItem">
            <input type="text" v-model="text">
            <input type="hidden" v-model="id">
            <input type="submit" value="enviar">    
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

This component has a method that use `$emit` to add text item to a parent data:

```
addItem () {
    const { text } = this
    this.$emit('block', text)
},
```

Here is markup on my main file:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <BlockForm @block="addBlock"/>
        <Message v-bind:message="message"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the script:

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        BlockForm,
        Message
    },
    data () {
        return {
            message : []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addBlock (text) {
            const { message } = this
            const key = message.length
            message.push({
                name: text,
                order: key
            })
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: Message component list all items create by BlockForm component and stored inside message array. I add a edit button for each item inside Message list. How can I pass item text to be edited in BlockForm component?

Comment: create one data property to store which message is editing, then bind this data property to one prop  (like `prop-text` )of `<BlockForm>`, inside `<BlockForm>`, create one data property then use one watch to copy latest value of `prop-text`. one click 'addBlock' button, emit that data property.

Comment: This is a bit confusing for a Vue newbie. But I will try here.

Comment: something like this: Message component tells parent component which message is editing, then parent component load that message to BlockForm, after click addBlock Button, BlockForm tells Parent component what have done (like what you have done already [emit one event=**block** to tell parent component to add new content to the message list]).

Comment: @marcelo2605 for this case u  should use  vuejs mixin and eventHub that can help you to communicate components with $on and $emit vuejs event. this link will help you : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just bind the input inside the BlockForm to a variable that is in the parent component. This way when you $emit from the child component, just add the value to the messages.

```
export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        BlockForm,
        Message
    },
    data () {
        return {
            message : [],
            inputVal: {
               text: '',
               id: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addBlock () {

            const key = this.message.length
            this.message.push({
                name: this.inputVal.text,
                order: this.inputVal.text.length // If the logic is different here, you can just change it
            })
            this.inputVal = {
               text: '',
               id: ''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you are calling the BlockForm,

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <BlockForm propVal="inputVal" @block="addBlock"/>
        <Message v-bind:message="message"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

and inside BlockForm,

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="addItem">
            <input type="text" v-model="propVal.text">
            <input type="hidden" v-model="probVal.id">
            <input type="submit" value="enviar">    
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now, when you press edit for existing message, simple assign that "Message" to inputVal data property mapping it to proper text and id.

Comment: Thanks! I made some adjustments you gave me the idea.

Comment: Yup. That was my plan all along